# I have problems to replace inf and -inf win nan in pandas

Tags: pandas, nan, infinite

I found a code on the web to replace `inf` and `-inf` with `np.nan`, however it did not work on my computer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [4.6, 5., np.inf]})
new_dataframe = a_dataframe.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
df
```

My output

```
    A
0   4.6
1   5.0
2   inf
```

Does somebody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

import pandas and numpy, then assign to the dataframe `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`. When you do `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` this does not update the dataframe it needs to be assigned with `=` for the change to happen.

Also, for some reason in the code you provided there is new_dataframe and a_dataframe, which have nothing to do with df. Try the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [4.6, 5., np.inf]})
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
print(df)
```